# PHP content in HTML Code with If conditon

Tags: php, html

I am trying to show text content just with a PHP if condition but I have several errors and I don’t see where is the error could someone help me with this, here is the code:

```
<?php
  if(
     isset($_POST['send']) &&
     !validateDiscp($_POST['Discp']) || !validateSize($_POST['Size'])
  ) : ?>

<div id="error">
  <ul>
    <?php if(!validateDiscp($_POST['Discp'])):?>
     <li><strong>Discription:</strong>Discription need to be larger then 10!</li>
    <?php endif?>
    <?php if(!validateSize($_POST['Size'])):?>
     <li><strong>Invalid Size:</strong> Size needs to bi S M L XL</li>
    <?php endif ?>
      </ul>
</div>

<?php elseif(isset($_POST['send'])):?>
<div id="error" class="valid">
  <ul>
    <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong> All fields are OK ;)</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ;?>
```

Comment: A couple of `<?php endif ?>` miss an ending semicolon - on the other hand there is a `;)` smile :PP

Comment: I can't see anything that's wrong with the syntax. Can you post the error messages?

Comment: Hi,sorry but i dont see where i am missed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the whole outside block. Instead do:

```
 <? if( isset($_POST['send'])&&  !validateDiscp($_POST['Discp']) || !validateSize($_POST['Size']) ) { ?>
        <div id="error">
            <ul>
               <?php if(!validateDiscp($_POST['Discp'])) { ?>
                    <li><strong>Discription:</strong> Discription need to be larger then 10!</li>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if(!validateSize($_POST['Size'])) { ?>
                    <li><strong>Invalid Size:</strong> Size needs to bi S M L XL</li>
                <?php } else { 
        $nothing = true;
                 ?>



            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php if( isset( $nothing ) and isset($_POST['send'] ) ) { ?>
        <div id="error" class="valid">
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Congratulations!</strong> All fields are OK ;)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

     <? } ?>
```

I think the flaw in your logic ist hat you have an else statement that is dangling. Instead add a little logic to detect when the else case is hit and add your additional logic and your good to go.

Comment: Hi there 
I need to explain a bit the behavior expected:
This code need to check 1st  if the from  is sent if yes he checks if the functions:
validateSize and validateDiscp are false 
if yes he need to show message o1 or 2
if it is sent and functions return true he show message 3
If it is not sent it no thing is showed.

Answer (score 1):

All the `endif`s need to have `;` after them. Also, I'm not sure if this is an actual error or just the code getting wrapped, but make sure your first `if` is all on one line.

Comment: Some one have an other idea ???? i tink that the  is that isset($_POST['send2']) is alwiase true

Comment: OK, then I'd need to see the HTML for the form.

Answer (score 0):

after changing things it is working here is the code

```
        <?php if(isset($_POST['send']) && !validateDiscp($_POST['Discp'])|| !validateSize($_POST['Size'])  ):?>

    <div id="error">
                <ul>
                    <?php if(!validateDiscp($_POST['Discp'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Discription:</strong> Discription need to be larger then 10!</li>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if(!validateSize($_POST['Size'])):?>
                        <li><strong>Invalid Size:</strong> Size needs to bi S M L XL</li>
                    <?php endif; ?>



                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php elseif(isset($_POST['send']) ):?>
```